# Database Object Monitoring

Tags: sql-server, database

I'd like to monitor the DB object in SQL Server. If someone add/modify the table/SP/view I need to get notified or logged in another table.

Is this possible? Do we need to use any other third party DB tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using DDL Triggers (plus Database mail)

- [Using DDL Triggers in SQL Server 2005 to Capture Schema Changes](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes)
- [Designing DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx)
- [DDL Events for Use with DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189871%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2005 DDL Trigger Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2005-ddl-trigger-workbench/)